# calling the same activity using a for

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, onclick

Hi everyone.
I'm new in android and I'm working on an app in which I need to recall the same activity to enter the information of a variable amount of entities (passengers).
I have the following:

```
btnContinue3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
    for (int i=0; i<Pssngr; i++){
        passenger[i] = new
            Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pasajeros.class);
            startActivity(passenger[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

`Pssngr` is the amount of passsengers or entites that need a unique activity to get their information entered.
The trigger is the button then the activities will be called one by one following an array

I try this code but after clicking on the button the app crashed.
Please someone help me find a way to make this work.
thanks

Comment: You should not stack so many Activities.  Not only is this bad practice for an Android App, but it will more than likely confuse the user on why so many Activities are opening, and what they need to do.  Make it simple.

Comment: would you consider putting a "next passenger" button in your first Pasajeros.class, and let it be the one that open up the next activity?

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because You are trying to start x number of Activities at once.
If You have to run new Activity for each of Passengers best in this scenario will be [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

I beliver effect You trying to get is that user clicks on button just once and activities for each passenger will open one after another.

To do it in method onClick You will start only first activity, don't use loop.

You start consequently next activities in [onActivitiyResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gustek mentions above, a better way to approach this would be to have one activity and just pass the different values from the parent (PassengersAvitivty) activity through the intent as below:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(PassengersAcitivty.this, PassengersEntityActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("PASSENGER_FIRSTNAME", passenger[i].getName());
    intent.putExtra("PASSENGER_LASTNAME", passenger[i].getLastName());
    intent.putExtra("PASSENGER_EMAIL", passenger[i].getEmail());
    startActivity(intent);
```

and here is how you can retrieve them on your activity (PassengerEntityActivity)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            firstname = extras.getString("PASSENGER_FIRSTNAME");
            lastname = extras.getString("PASSENGER_LASTNAME");
            email = extras.getString("PASSENGER_EMAIL");


        }
        else
        {
            //Log.v("NO VALUE", "OOPS");
        }
```

I can clarify further if needed.